# How to rewrite this matrix form

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I had this equation.
\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  g_{1,1} & g_{1,2} & \cdots & g_{1,n} \\
  g_{2,1} & g_{2,2} & \cdots & g_{2,n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  g_{n,1} & g_{n,2} & \cdots & g_{n,n}
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    p_1\\
    \vdots\\
\vdots\\
    p_n
  \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    x_1\\
    \vdots\\
\vdots\\
    x_n
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Is there any way that I can find 
\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{x_1}\\
    \vdots\\
\vdots\\
        \frac{1}{x_n}
  \end{pmatrix}
in terms of G matrix and p vector?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x_k}=\frac{1}{G_k.p}$ where $G_k$ is the k'th row of G (and the dot product is not 0)is probably the answer you don't want...

Comment: Is your question already answered? Then @Paul should post the comment as answer an the answer should be accepted or the post deleted...